# Usage of ShardedJedisPool in a Non-Cluster Redis Environment in lastest version: Deprecated or Alternatives?

Tags: java, jedis

I understand that ShardedJedisPool has been deprecated, and I would like to confirm if ShardedJedisPool is still available in any form in version 4.3.0. If not, how can I achieve the same functionality? Should I downgrade the Jedis version? Is that recommended? Or any Alternatives in the latest version?